# Linux - Cannot Remove File, error "Operation is not permitted"

Tags: linux, unix, redhat

I try to remove some file in Linux (RHEL7), it was error as "Operation is not permitted".
At first time, I check attribute by command "lsattr". There are two flags for this file, that are 'r' and 'e'.

I run chattr -i , this file will remain 'e'. But I try to delete again, it still error "Operation is not permitted". What can I do? (This file has permission as 777, and I used root user)

Remark: I think this file come from some malware attack.

Comment: `e` attribute cannot be changed: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lsattr.1.html Curiously, `r` is not listed as a possible attribute in the man page. Why do you think this is malware? What file is this?

Answer (score 0):

UNIX/Linux has a command you can use for knowing if a file is used by a process, `lsof`. So, using `lsof | grep "filename"` might give some insights in what process is currently holding your file. Keep out that this process might have parent processes, which you can find using the `PPID` field of the `ps -ef` command.

Comment: I have tried to check by fuser, but there is no process to used this file.

Comment: ... and `lsof`? When I open a file, I see it with `lsof`, not with `fuser`.